# 550 5.7.1 error message followed by an encoded string

Tags: smtp

We are trying to send simple test emails to a remote server (not under our control) and we get rejected with this message:

```
550 5.7.1 Message denied by policy. gggruggvucftvghtrhhoucdtuddrfeelgedrieejgdefudcutefuodetggdotefrucfrrhhofhhilhgvmecuggftfghnshhusghstghrihgsvgdpucfhtffggffotefknfenuceurghilhhouhhtmecufedttdenucgorfhhihhshhhinhhgqdfkphculdeftddtmdenucfjughrpefhvffusedttddttddttddtnecuhfhrohhmpeggihhtvgiiucfirggsohhruceoghgrsghorhdrvhhithgviiesmhhishhkohhltghiuhhghihvvgguihhkrghmrghrrgdrhhhuqeenucfkphepudekkedrudeiiedrieelrdduieegnecurfgrrhgrmhephhgvlhhopegtmhhsphhorhhtrghlrdgtohhmthhrrghnshdrhhhupdhinhgvthepudekkedrudeiiedrieelrdduieegpdhmrghilhhfrhhomhepghgrsghorhdrvhhithgviiesmhhishhkohhltghiuhhghihvvgguihhkrghmrghrrgdrhhhupdhrtghpthhtoheptghhrhhishdrfhhrvggvmhgrihhlsehfrhgvvghmrghilhdrhhhu
```

The gggrugg.. is probably some kind of encoded error message, what encoding can this be?

Earlier the same server encoded the errors with base64. According to mail-tester.com we have a 10/10 spam score, with DKIM,SPF and DMARC all set up correctly and our server is not on any blacklist. The remote server probably uses Vade-Retro or Vadesecure for spam filtering.

Comment: You should send a note to their postmaster@theirdomain.tld and ask what the log message means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did as @Aaron suggested. They actually had a phone number and I called them, I was told to send an email with the rejected and the original email attached in standard mailbox format. They forwarded these to Vadesecure and the issue was fixed after a bit of back and forth, the emails now go through as expected.

The encoding of the error message was not revealed.